# custom post type metaboxes not saving

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, metabox

I have the following code. I am trying to enter data into the custom metabox and then save it. When I go to view it has entered a post, however the name column has nothing in it. Also when I hit save I get a post.php page with a blank page, is this a page I need to create in my theme and have it go back to the current page or something.

```
<?
/**
*   Custom post-type booktime
**/

add_action('init', 'booktime_register');

function booktime_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('booktime', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('booktime', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('add new', 'add new'),
        'add_new_item' => __('add new item'),
        'edit_item' => __('edit item'),
        'new_item' => __('new item'),
        'view_item' => __('view item'),
        'search_items' => __('search items'),
        'not_found' =>  __('nothing here'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('not found in trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments','custom-fields','revisions')
      );

    register_post_type( 'booktime' , $args );
}

?>

<?php

add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "booktime_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-booktime_columns", "booktime_edit_columns");

function booktime_custom_columns($column){
    global $post;

    switch ($column) {
        case "name":
            the_excerpt();
        break;
        case "address":
            $custom = get_post_custom();
            echo $custom["address"][0];
        break;
        case "phone":
            $custom = get_post_custom();
            echo $custom["phone"][0];
        break;
        case "date":
            $custom = get_post_custom();
            echo $custom["date"][0];
        break;
        case "bottles":
            $custom = get_post_custom();
            echo $custom["bottles"][0];
        break;

    }
}

function booktime_edit_columns($columns){
    $columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Post should show",
        "description" => "name",
        "address" => "address",
        "phone" => "phone",
        "date" => "date",
        "bottles" => "bottles"
    );

    return $columns;
}

?>

<?php
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init_booktime");

function admin_init_booktime(){

    add_meta_box("name", "name", "name", "booktime", "normal", "low");

}
?>

<?php
function name() {
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $name = ( !empty($custom["name"][0]) ) ? $custom["name"][0]: "";
    ?>
    <p><label>Name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/></p>
    <?php
}
?>

<?php
add_action('save_post', 'save_details_booktime');

function save_details_booktime(){
    global $post;
    $custom_meta_fields = array( 'name' );

    foreach( $custom_meta_fields as $custom_meta_field ):
        if(isset($_POST[$custom_meta_field]) && $_POST[$custom_meta_field] != ""):
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_meta_field, $_POST[$custom_meta_field]);
        endif;
    endforeach;

}
?>
```

Comment: Im sorry if I don't follow. How do I update the meta, add it or delete it.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, disregard my last comment (I deleted it) as it was incorrect in accuracy anyways. See Bainternet's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the field name from `name` to something else since `name` is a reserved word and could be whats causing the blank page, also its better practice to prefix you field names.

Now in your save_details_booktime function make sure you are no the right post type and not in autosave, something like this:

```
 function save_details_booktime($post_id ) {
    global $post;   
    //skip auto save
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    /check for you post type only
    if( $post->post_type != "booktime" ) {
        return;

    }
    $custom_meta_fields = array( 'name' ); //change from name to something else

    foreach( $custom_meta_fields as $custom_meta_field ){
        if(isset($_POST[$custom_meta_field]) && $_POST[$custom_meta_field] != ""){
            update_post_meta($post_id, $custom_meta_field, $_POST[$custom_meta_field]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `save_post` action will return the ID of the post you're saving for you.

You may also want to verify the permissions the user has to update the post and make sure a task such as Autosave isn't running. I've added these in below.

(Also read Bainternet's answer)

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details_booktime');

function save_details_booktime( $id ){

    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;

    // Check permissions
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $id ) )
            return;
    } else {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $id ) )
            return;
    }

    $custom_meta_fields = array( 'some_name' );

    foreach( $custom_meta_fields as $custom_meta_field ):
        // Grab the existing meta data (will return an empty string if none)
        $meta_exists = get_post_meta( $id, $custom_meta_field, true );

        // If the meta doesn't match what was $_POST'ed
        if( $_POST[$custom_meta_field] != $meta_exists && $_POST[$custom_meta_field] != '' )
            update_post_meta( $id, $custom_meta_field, $_POST[$custom_meta_field] );

        // If the meta does exist, but the new data is blank, delete it
        if( $meta_exists != '' && $_POST[$custom_meta_field] == '' )
            delete_post_meta( $id, $custom_meta_field );

    endforeach;

}
```

Be sure to read the articles on [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta), [delete_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta), and [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) for more information on the functions used above.

Comment: the Codex says: (`update_post_meta`) may be used in place of `add_post_meta()` function.